# How to install gwt-validation with gwt-2.4.0

Tags: gwt, gwt-validation

I would like to use [Gwt-Validation](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/) with Gwt 2.4.0.

I have in my gwt.xml file :

```
  <inherits name="javax.validation.Validation" />
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.validation.Validation" />
  <inherits name='com.em.validation.Validation' />
```

Like in the documentation, I have the following code :

```
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
...

ValidatorFactory factory =
    Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().buildValidatorFactory();

Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
```

The problem is that I have the following error :

> Deferred binding result type 'javax.validation.ValidationFactory' should not be abstract.
>
> //... beautiful stacktrace with mainly  :
>
> Deferred binding failed for 'javax.validation.ValidatorFactory' (did
>   you forget to inherit a required module?)

My pom.xml contains :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.gwt-validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-validation</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

What can I do ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the java imports.

In the following code :

```
ValidatorFactory factory =
    Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().buildValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
```

I imported :

`com.google.gwt.validation.client` instead of `javax.validation`

No error at java compile time ! Just the errors above at gwt compile time (or runtime with the hosted mode).

Comment: This is a pretty common problem.  I did that to myself the other day when adding a new unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my GWT.XML file :

```
<inherits name="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator" />
<replace-with class="com.example.client.MyValidatorFactory">
    <when-type-is class="javax.validation.ValidatorFactory" />
</replace-with>
```

I defined MyValidatorFactory like this :

```
public final class MyValidatorFactory extends AbstractGwtValidatorFactory {

    /**
     * Validator marker for the Validation Sample project. Only the classes
     * listed in the {@link GwtValidation} annotation can be validated.
     */
    @GwtValidation(value = { Customer.class, License.class, Account.class })
    public interface MyValidator extends Validator {
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractGwtValidator createValidator() {
        return GWT.create(GwtValidator.class);
    }
}
```

In my classpath I have :

```
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final-sources.jar
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar
```

Now you can validate your domain objects  :

```
    Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Account>> violations = validator.validate(account);
```

And the same validation then **also works server-side** :

```
private static ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().buildValidatorFactory();
Set<ConstraintViolation<DomainResource>> violations = factory.getValidator().validate(account);
```

Good stuff!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not using Hibernate.

Comment: You dont have to use hibernate for this, I am not using Hibernate either. But hibernate-validator is the default provider for validation on the server side.